# How to make Python decision tree more understandable?

Tags: python, tree, scikit-learn, data-analysis

I have a data file. The last column of the data has +1 and -1 distinguishing variables. I also have the id names of each column in a separate file.

e.g.

```
1 2 3 4 1
5 6 7 8 1
9 1 2 3 -1
4 5 6 7 -1
8 9 1 2 -1
```

and for each column I have Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4, Q5 names respectively.

I want to implement decision tree classifier so I wrote the following code:

```
import numpy
from sklearn import tree

print('Reading data from ' + fileName);
data = numpy.loadtxt(fileName);
print('Getting ids from ', idFile)
idArray = numpy.genfromtxt('cleanedID.csv', dtype='str')

print('Adding ids')
print('data dimensions: ', data.shape)
print('idArray dimensions: ', idArray.shape)
data = numpy.append(idArray, data, axis = 0)


y = data[:,-1]
x = data[:, 1:-1]

classifier = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth = depth)
classifier = classifier.fit(x, y)

with open('graph.dot', 'w') as file:
    tree.export_graphviz(classifier, out_file = file)

file.close()
```

I used graphviz to convert .dot file to .png file.

The problem is that the decision tree which looks something like:
[image]

I don't get what X[number] means. I searched and found that value = [5 0] means class 5 has 0 objects and class 0 has 5 objects but I have only +1 and -1 distinguishing variables. Is there anyway I can tweak this decision tree so that I can see the column names (Q1, Q2, Q3....) in the decision tree picture so I can understand that what this means?

Thanks

Comment: How many columns does your data have?

Comment: @yangjie It has 603 columns

Comment: `X[n]` simply means the value in nth column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Value = [5  0]` means that the first class has 5 members and the second class has 0 members. For you, the class order is probably `[-1 1]`.

As for column names: As yangjie pointed out, `X[158]` means the 159th column (zero-indexing). The rule is pretty spelled out already: `X[168]<=1.5` means for a given row, the tree is deciding whether to go left or right based on the value of the 168th column and how it compares to 1.5.

You can add column names using the `feature_names` optional argument to [export_graphviz](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.export_graphviz.html#sklearn.tree.export_graphviz)

Comment: yangjie pointed that out. You have said that X[168] <= 1.5 means for a given row, the tree is deciding whether to go left or right based on the value of the 168th column but 168th column has 6475 values (rows). And how can I use the column names (Q1, Q2, Q3, ...) in the decision tree instead of X[n]?

Comment: Edited to say how to add feature names. Your question about number of rows is not making sense. A decision tree acts on a single row. For a single row, it is trying to reach an end leaf by, at each junction, comparing a particular column value in that row to a threshold. For a single row, column 168 only has one value. If you are talking about training, then the "samples" number is the most information that can be reasonably displayed: this many samples went left, that many samples went right (samples==rows).

Comment: Thanks! You solved my problem. Just a quick question, is the order of classes in value = [a, b] in condescending order?

Comment: Yes, they go from most arrogant to least. Actually, they are typically in lexicographic order (i.e., put them in a Python list and sort).