# How to visualize decision tree it in python?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, graphviz

I created a decision tree and tried to follow an answer([Visualizing decision tree in scikit-learn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27817994/visualizing-decision-tree-in-scikit-learn/27818170#27818170)) to visualize it in python,but still don't work:

```
import pandas as pd
score_v2 = pd.read_csv("C:/TEST_RF_CSV_simple.csv",encoding = "cp950")

from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier

score_X = score_v2
score_y = score_v2.buy_lf
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
score_X, score_y, test_size=0.3)

from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
tree=DecisionTreeClassifier(criterion = 'entropy', max_depth=3, 
random_state=0)
tree.fit(X_train, y_train)
tree_1 = tree.fit(X_train, y_train)

from sklearn.tree import export_graphviz
dotfile = open("D:/dtree2.dot", 'w')
tree.export_graphviz(dtree, out_file = dotfile, feature_names = 
X.columns)
dotfile.close()
```

my error was:

```
AttributeError: 'DecisionTreeClassifier' object has no attribute 
'export_graphviz'
```

Could any masters help me with solving the problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python Decision Tree GraphViz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34144134/python-decision-tree-graphviz)

Answer (score 1):

`export_graphviz` is a function of `sklearn.tree`, not from the classifier:

```
from sklearn.tree import export_graphviz
export_graphviz(tree, out_file=dotfile, feature_names=X.columns)
```

Comment: Thanks. If I want to work it, did you know how to refine it?

Comment: Such as this question's picture.(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31786347/how-to-make-python-decision-tree-more-understandable)

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question. You get a dot file for graphviz out of this command. Then you can convert it to a png. What do you mean by "work it" and "refine it"?

Comment: "refine". The final goal is output the picture of decision tree.

Comment: Use graphviz (dot, to be precise) to convert the dot to a png. Look at the duplicate.

Comment: Thanks. But our computer didn't install pydot2, did you have other way?

Comment: Please, look at the duplicate, there are 3 different ways!

Comment: I tried this,still no...
    with open("classifier.txt", "w") as f:
        f = tree.export_graphviz(tree, out_file=f)

Comment: You get a `dot` file, then you need to convert it.

Comment: Hi Matthieu, When I convert dot, still have error. I will input raw data and run again. And read other book.Thanks for helping.